# as densely packed blocks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-masonry

please help solve the problem. for dense packing blocks I used a popular plugin masonry.

my resulting [code](http://jsfiddle.net/6ashzfo6/3/) is not worked. but I used the method described in the [documentation](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/fluid.html)

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
  columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 5;
  }
});
```

css:

```
#container{
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    #container .item{
        width: 33.3%;
        background: red;
        float: left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle references the [masonry v3](http://masonry.desandro.com/) library.

For this syntax (http://jsfiddle.net/6ashzfo6/4/):

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.box',
  // set columnWidth a fraction of the container width
  columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
    return containerWidth / 5;
  }
});
```

Use the [v2.1.08](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/2.1.08/jquery.masonry.min.js) as in the documentation you linked to.